# Android Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name integrating ingo sdk

Tags: android, android-studio, android-build, android-build-type

when I integrate an ingo SDK in my project I use to get the following  error

> Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the
>   given name

[image]

Build tools of module(project)

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
dependencies {
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.0'
}
```

Build tools for ingo SDK

```
android {
        compileSdkVersion 23
        buildToolsVersion '23.0.0'
        defaultConfig {
            minSdkVersion 14
            targetSdkVersion 23
            multiDexEnabled true
        }
    dependencies {
     compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.0'
    }
```

Please help me solving this issue.